# Python to add a line after the exact match from the blocks of same pattern in a file

Tags: python

I have a file like this :

```
tablename-0-username=
tablename-0-password=
tablename-0-endpoint=

tablename-1-username=
tablename-1-password=
tablename-1-endpoint=
```

In python how to add a line after `tablename-username`
The keywords are like `tablename-0-id=test` and `tablename-1-id=test1`

Is there anyway in python I can create a outfile like this

```
tablename-0-username=
tablename-0-id=test
tablename-0-password=
tablename-0-endpoint=


tablename-1-username=
tablename-1-id=test1
tablename-1-password=
tablename-1-endpoint=
```

I don't want 2 files to be create, the operation should be in same file. I have created like this, but this one inserts after every other matching pattern.

```
find = "tablename-" + id
with open(config_file_name, "r") as in_file:
    buf = in_file.readlines()

with open(config_file_name, "w") as out_file:
   for line in buf:
       if find in line:
            line = line + pattern + "\n"
       out_file.write(line)
```

Comment: is the indentation on purpose or accidental? newline character won't add indentation to the text

Comment: indentation issue? where in the file? if so, then it's accidental.

Comment: what is `pattern`? Kindly provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: @Yatin NVM, I followed @Prune's suggestion and i manage to works it fine now. Just to answer your question, pattern is `tablename-{id}-` but the string to be inserted are `tablename-0-id=test`

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is that, for some reason, you chose to search for a dysfunctional pattern.  You have to search for something that accurately discriminates the lines yof interest from everything else.  Instead, try

```
find = "-username="
```

... which uniquely identifies the lines, just as you specified in the problem description.

Answer (score 1):

You can try :

```py
find = "-endpoint" 
with open(config_file_name, "r") as in_file:
    buf = in_file.readlines()

with open(config_file_name, "w") as out_file:
   for line in buf:
       if find in line:
            line = line + pattern + "\n"
       out_file.write(line)
```

This will insert a new line (`\n` character) after every occurrence of the word `endpoint`

Comment: this is exactly i did.

Answer (score 0):

```
with open(config_file_name, "r") as in_file:
    buf = in_file.readlines()
with open(config_file_name, "w") as out_file:
   for line in buf:
       line = line.split('=')[0]
       if 'username' in line :
            # You can also write a newline into the file in this block. 
            line = line + pattern + "\n"
       out_file.write(line)
```

This will check for the phrase `username` in each line before '=' as the username can be the string `"username"`.